# Objective C: Record audio from speaker output?

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-audio, avaudiorecorder

I am trying to make a Mac app that will be able to record the audio that is being played through the speakers/headphones.

Is the only way to do this to have it play over the speakers and then pick it up via the microphone? Or can you capture it before it leaves?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SoundFlower is an applcation that does this. Check out it's source code [here](https://code.google.com/p/soundflower/).

Comment: The Google Code repository hasn't been updated in a long time. You might want to take a look at one of the forks on their GitHub repository for more recent updates and fixes: https://github.com/cycling74/Soundflower.

Comment: is there any option for iOS

Comment: Unfortunately, WavTap doesn't appear to be a viable answer anymore. As reported in their repo "WavTap is completely broken on El Capitan due to Apple's [System Integrity Protection]"